# Configuring libGL, DRI, and swrast on ubuntu - Dell 2950 hardware

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg

I'm trying to run https://github.com/schenc3/InteractiveROSETTA which is an X wrapper over pyRosetta.  It launches and loads the initial splash screen, but quickly dies with the error:

```
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
The program 'python' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'GLXBadContext'
```

When I launch firefox I get the exact same errors but ff does successfully load.

The first swrast_dri.so does not exist (no tls directory).   However, the second one does exist.  When I run glxinfo it fails with the same error so I'm assuming that it's my configuration of libGL.   This is a Dell 2950 rack server and the output of lspci is:

0e:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] ES1000 (rev 02)

driconf says

```
 "could not detect any configurable direct rendering capable devices"
```

and then sends me to expert move where I have NFI what I'm doing.  I would like help understanding what dri, swrast, and libGL are and how to configure them.  I'm particularly interested in hearing either a clear "yes that should work" or "no theres no way that will work".

Comment: Dell 2950. Could be your 10 year old 'ATI ES1000' isn't supported by the Ubuntu [unknown] OS ? `swrast_dri.so` is provided by the package `libgl1-mesa-dri` ... and mesa discontinued support for legacy hardware some years ago.

Comment: Totally agree that it's old hardware.   But X runs perfectly fine otherwise and that is why I was leaning towards "yes that should work"

Comment: Did you find solution to this problem?